# Next js Multizone rewrites: second app not linking back to orginial app

Tags: next.js

Set up a multizone with rewrites following the docs everything works fine except for linking back to the original app from the second app. I've tried href='/' and href='../' and even href={"/"}.

```
<div className="menu">
        <Link href="/">
          <img className="w-10 hover:brightness-200 hover:grayscale" src="/hotdog-truck.png" alt="Hotdog Truck"></img>
        </Link>
      </div>
```

thought about adding rewrites to both apps but that doesn't seem like the thing to do. Here's my next.config file for the second app.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  basePath: "/blog",
  images: {
    domains: ["gateway.ipfscdn.io", "i.seadn.io", "ipfs.io"],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```